# Where can I pass the fetch_size on a PreparedStatement in the Cassandra Python driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-python-driver

I am trying to set the fetch_size on a PreparedStatement on Python for Cassandra driver 3.11.

I can see this is possible on SimpleStatement but I am having problems to find how to use it for PreparedStatement.

Since PreparedStatement is a result of `Session.prepare(query)` ... I don't know where to pass that param ... or it it's even possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the `fetch_size` attribute on the `PreparedStatement` object. Here's an example:

```
    user_ps = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM users_by_email WHERE email = ?")
    user_ps.fetch_size = 100
```

Alternatively, it is possible to set a default for the session with:

```
    session.default_fetch_size = 100
```

For details, see [the `Session` API Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/latest/api/cassandra/cluster/#cassandra.cluster.Session). Cheers!